# Trying to make the script end if Var isn't an Int

Tags: python

Just making a simple dice game with Python for schoolwork. Here's the Script I'm using:

```
from random import randint

print("Welcome to my Dice Game.")
print("")
input("Press ENTER to Begin.")

print("")

_Choice = int(input("Enter the number of sides you want on your dice: "))
print("")

if isinstance( _Choice, int ):
    number = (randint(1,_Choice))
    print("Your dice has been rolled...")
    print("Your number is:")
    print(number)
    print("")
    input("Press ENTER to Exit")
    exit()   
else:
    print("You have selected an invalid Dice Option")
    print("Dice Game is ending")
    print("")
    input("Press ENTER to exit manually")
    exit()
```

Comment: Ignore all the comments at the end. I had to reach the character minimum.

Comment: This is not a good idea to fill the left characters with some kind of spam. Consider rephrasing your question. TBH in your question I can't see what are your doubts.

Comment: Your question is?

Comment: And...?
[Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the whole `else` statement or two last lines from it.

Your script will end up reaching the end of file

Moreover, in your example there's no way that your variable could be something different than int. In case the user inputs some incorrect data in:

```
_Choice = int(input("Enter the number of sides you want on your dice: "))
```

`int(...)` will throw an exception that will terminate your script when not catched.

You should rather do it in a following way:

```
try:
    _Choice = int(input("Enter the number of sides you want on your dice: "))
except ValueError:
    print "Error log message here"
    sys.exit()

# the rest of your script without unimportant type check:
number = (randint(1,_Choice))
print("Your dice has been rolled...")
print("Your number is:")
print(number)
print("")
input("Press ENTER to Exit")
sys.exit()
```